# vscode gdb debugger failed: bad DWP hash table

Tags: vscode-debugger, envoyproxy

i want to debug envoy with vscode in windows,

after success build with

```bash
tools/vscode/generate_debug_config.py //source/exe:envoy-static --args "-c envoy.yaml"
```

i try to start debugger, but got such error below. is there anyone can help me ?

[image: envoy-remote-debug-error]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use --debugger lldb, works for me. Since the macOS will use lldb as debugger, while gdb works for other system.
Based on the config in this article. https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/article/1912591?from=15425